# Input Binding in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form and a live preview of what the form will create.

My model

```
//campaign.js
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  body: attr('string')
});
```

In the route

```
// new.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model () {
    return this.store.createRecord('campaign', {
      title: null,
      body: null
    })
  }
});
```

My current implementation uses a component for the input

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  keyPress(event) {
    // binding code
  }
});
```

And in the template

```
{{#title-input}}
{{/title-input}}
<div id="title-preview"></div>
```

My Feeling is that there is a cleaner or more idiomatic way to do this. I am new to ember so thank you for any help

Comment: you can call `return this.store.createRecord('campaign')`, the properties will be undefined by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the use of Components are compelling they aren't required for capturing form input in ember.  For what what its worth.  For simple form input the route could be:

```
setupController() {
    Ember.set('controller','newCampaign', {}); //set empty newCampaign
},

# Action hash would create the new record but only when you have some data.
actions: {
    createCampaign(newCampaign) {
            let newRecord = this.store.createRecord('campaign', newCampaign); //create record
            newRecord.save().then(( /* response */ ) => {
                this.transitionTo('campaigns'); //transition to different page.
            }, (error) => { // Deal with an adapter error
                //handle error
                //rollback if necessary
            });
    }
}
```

The form or template could be:

```
{{input name="title" id="title" value=newCampaign.title type="text"}}
{{input name="body" id="body" value=newCampaign.body type="text"}}
```

Just a suggestion.

Jeff